# Deploying large models on sagemaker serverless inference endpoints gives timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

> **Unable to successfully stand up your model within the allotted 180 second timeout. Please ensure that downloading your model artifacts,
> starting your model container and passing the ping health checks can
> be completed within 180 seconds.**

Following this doc -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/large-model-inference-uncompressed.html
But this also is giving

> ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter
> in PrimaryContainer: "ModelDataSource", must be one of:
> ContainerHostname, Image, ImageConfig, Mode, ModelDataUrl,
> Environment, ModelPackageName, InferenceSpecificationName,
> MultiModelConfig

is there any other way to host large models ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to host Large models on Serverless Inference, please use RealTime endpoints as they support GPU instances. Examples for the same can be found here - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/inference/generativeai/llm-workshop

Comment: I hosted it using RealTime endpoints successfully, but real-time endpoints is not of much use as of now because of the low traffic, is there any other alternative where we can host in any other way with lower cost ?

Comment: also because of the 60-second limitation in real-time inference it is not suitable for our case

Comment: RT endpoints timeout can be increased to 120s, please talk to your AWS Support team to raise that request. Another thing to consider is Async endpoints as they have 60mins timeout and you can scale the instances down to zero when not in use.

Comment: okay will try with async endpoints